# Enable personal hotspot programatically in iOS using Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am looking for a way to enable personal Hotspot programatically in iOS using Swift or Objective-C but did not see any API or way to achieve that.

My question is that even possible to do that?

Does Apple allow that?

Also as per Apple Developer Documentation [HotSpot Helper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper) what are the controls we can achieve that ??

```
Hotspot Communication
Hotspot helpers can use these APIs to communicate with the hotspot even when Wi-Fi is not the default route.

func bind(to: NEHotspotHelperCommand)
    Binds a URL request to the network interface associated with the hotspot helper command instance.
    In-Provider Networking
    Network APIs for use by all types of NetworkExtension providers and by hotspot helpers.
```

Comment: Nope. There's no public API for it https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/113933

Comment: @CodeDifferent, Just Curios what is this link about 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/hotspot_helper
Apple Developer Documentation ??

Comment: "Hotspot" is a particular type of network that requires an authentication interstitial be passed by the user before being granted access to the broader LAN or Internet/WAN. While similarly named, this is *not* the same as the personal hotspot feature you seem to be after.

Comment: @esqew, is there any entitlement to access the private api?

Comment: If there is such an entitlement, you would need to discuss with Apple. They have many special-case entitlements for specific 3rdparty products. If you have a particularly compelling requirement, then they may be able to help you. I would start by opening a [DTS](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) (now apparently called a TSI?) to discuss with them. No one here can tell you what Apple will allow you in a private deal, but the answer to your question based on publicly available tools is "no."

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier, I already requested to Apple for the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible. From Apple's Forums:

> There’s no way to do this programmatically. You can get the iOS device’s current Wi-Fi network SSID using
> `CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo`
> , but there’s no way to get the corresponding credentials.

If iOS did allow this, this would be a privacy and security risk. There is no private API to do this either. However, as Pushkraj Lanjekar said,

> You can just open device `Settings` view from app.

There is **no way** to programatically control personal hotspot on an iOS device.
This Apple Forums link may be helpful, however; https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/113933.

Answer (score 3):

Apple don't provide any API to Turn On/Off Personal Hotspot. Rather, you can't change any user setting via code. You can just open device `Settings` view from app.

Apple's privacy policies will not allow you to do this.